# Search all occurances in XML data

Tags: sql, xml

My table has a column with xml data.

e.g.:

```
    <Protokolldaten>
    <old>
        <Artikel>
            <Number>111072</Number>
            <Description>Ralvioli</Description>
            <Term>
                <To>12/12/12</To>
                <From>10/10/10</From>
            </Term>
        </Artikel>
    </old>
    <newWert>
        <Article>
            <Number>111072</Number>
            <Description>Ravioli</Description>
            <Term>
                <To>12/12/12</To>
                <From>10/10/10</From>
                <AnotherField>Ravioli</AnotherField>
            </Term>
        </Article>
    </newWert>
</Protokolldaten>
```

I want to find all occurances with ravioli in it and list the attribut name aswell. But it should search only inside the newWert section:

e.g.

```
Data       | Attributename
Ravioli    | Description
Ravioli    | AnotherField
```

Someone can give me a quick start how to do it? I know how to search a specific attribute, unfortunately I dont know the exact attribut, the text can be everywhere.

**UPDATE**

This is a start, but still I only want to search only the newWert section:

```
SELECT
x.y.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM Meldung m
CROSS apply m.Protokolldaten.nodes('//*[text()]') AS x(y)
WHERE Id = 'D81E6F2C-04C9-4F5B-9473-A45600EEA0DE'
```

Comment: start doing a draft (in this sample, they use LINQ) http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062310-1.aspx and if you get stuck, post your code so we may help you.

Comment: there are some mispelled words in your xml, is it intentional? (Ralvioli -> Ravioli)

Comment: Its intentional :) Its sorta a logfie. First part are old values, second are new ones.

Comment: I updated the post, i figured out a way to get all values now, but still cant filter out the old section

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this:

```sql
select 'Ravioli' as Data,
       T.X.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(max)')
from dbo.Meldung m
  cross apply m.Protokolldaten.nodes('//newWert//text()[. = "Ravioli"]') as T(X);
```